# PHP не записывает строку в TXT-файл

Tags: php

Скрипт не записывает ничего в файл, если можно разъяснить почему?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>message</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <form class="" action="sell.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="mess" value="text">
        <input type="button" name="bth" value="sell">
      </form>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
<?php

if (isset( $_POST['bth'])) {
    echo 'Нажата кнопка';
    $sells = $_POST['mess'];
    $fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r+"); // Открываем файл в режиме записи
    $mytext = "($sells)\r\n"; // Исходная строка
    $test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); // Запись в файл
    if ($test) echo 'Данные в файл успешно занесены.';
    else echo 'Ошибка при записи в файл.';
    fclose($fp); //Закрытие файла
}
```

Comment: и что - происходит ошибка? нет ошибки, но ничего не записывается, записывается только последняя запись?

Comment: а там точно есть что записывать?

Comment: Ничего, ни ошибки, ни последней записи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>message</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="mess" value="text">
        <!-- для отправки формы тип инпута должен быть SUBMIT, тип BUTTON это просто кнопка -->
        <input type="submit" name="bth" value="sell">
      </form>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
<?php

if (isset( $_POST['bth'])) {
    echo 'Нажата кнопка';
    $sells = $_POST['mess'];
    $fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r+"); // Открываем файл в режиме записи
    $mytext = "($sells)\r\n"; // Исходная строка
    $test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); // Запись в файл
    if ($test) echo 'Данные в файл успешно занесены.';
    else echo 'Ошибка при записи в файл.';
    fclose($fp); //Закрытие файла
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял свою ошибку